# How to disable Kafka in Quarkus test?

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, quarkus

My application uses Kafka and Hibernate. For Kafka a running docker image is required. If I run a Quarkus test for Hibernate, the test fails if Kafka is not running. In my IDE this is not a problem, but in Jenkins there is no Kafka server available and the test fails because it cannot resolve the Kafka server.

Is it possible to disable Kafka in Quarkus tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of Microprofile's `Emitter` for sending messages to Kafka channel:

```
@Inject 
@Channel("hello")
Emitter<String> emitter;
```

By default, in case when there is no Kafka behind that emitter, it will create an in-memory message bus. So the docker image for Kafka would not be required.

Another solution would be to use `KafkaContainer` from [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/) to create a throwaway Kafka container for each test run.

You could check both examples in Alex Soto's [repository](https://github.com/lordofthejars/quarked-test/tree/test).
Look at `CheckoutProcess` class and corresponding component test and integration test.

Comment: We already use an emitter, but the problem is the server name for kafka which is only known in Docker. We are now trying TestContainers, this seems to adress our problem. Thx